# Как удалить строку QTableWidget

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

как сделать так чтобы в таблице пользователь выделял любой элемент в строке и при нажатии на кнопку удалялась вся строка, а в таблице tablewidget это было видно?

Comment: что значит "и в таблице tablewidget это было видно"

Answer (score 0):

Для этого можно воспользоваться методами: [QTableWidget.currentRow](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTableWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidget.currentRow) и [QTableWidget.removeRow](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTableWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidget.removeRow)

```py
# Слот нажатия кнопки
def buttonClicked(self):
    row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
    if row > -1: # Если есть выделенная строка/элемент
       self.tableWidget.removeRow(row)
       # Следующий вызов нужен для того, чтобы 
       # сбросить индекс выбранной строки (чтобы currentRow установился в -1)
       self.tableWidget.selectionModel().clearCurrentIndex()
```